# RDLC How to Group by row with time range

Tags: rdlc

I am using linq to get the value and passing this to the reportviewer.

Let say for a particular Date from Sept 29 8Am to Sept 30 8am.

I would say there is a shift from 8am of (date) to 8am of(next date)

How can i achieve a report like this?

```
Date                   Name   Value
Sept 29,2014 8:00 Am   mango    10
Sept 30,2014 8:00 Am   apple    20
Sum                             30

Sept 30,2014 9:00 Am   mango    30
Oct  01,2014 1:00 Am   apple    20   
Sum                             50
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To do any sort of grouping, you will need to have something in common between the records to do that grouping on.  It looks like you are trying to group data based on a 24 hour period starting at 8am on one day and going to 8am the next day.

One problem with this approach is that the end of the grouping includes the start of the next in terms of the date. So do you want to group the data from 8:00:00am to 7:59:59am the next day or 8:00:01am to 8:00:00am the next day.

Now once that decision has been done, then you could use a formula to create the grouping based on the data.
something like the following (**concept only**, will need adjusting to your situation)

`Grouping Date = (data.DateTime.TimeComponent >= 8:00:00am) then data.Date else data.Date - 1 day`

**EDIT**
so you would end up with as your data

```
    Date                   Name   Value   GroupingDate
    Sept 29,2014 8:00 Am   mango    10    Sept 29, 2014
    Sept 30,2014 8:00 Am   apple    20    Sept 29, 2014 
    Sept 30,2014 9:00 Am   mango    30    Sept 30, 2014
    Oct  01,2014 1:00 Am   apple    20    Sept 30, 2014
```

Comment: Hi Nathan

Thanks for answering my query.

To do any sort of grouping, you will need to have something in common between the records to do that grouping on. It looks like you are trying to group data based on a 24 hour period starting at 8am on one day and going to 8am the next day.-- Yes you are correct

What common should be between the records? Is the date column valid for that common records?

Comment: Not the way it is at the moment with the data shown. If I was to group based on Name for example then I would have two groups (Apple, Mango) with the various Date and values associated with that grouping. If you were just talking about an actual Day ( midnight to midnight) then you could just group on the Date without the time component, but because you want from 8am to 8am then you will need to use a formula to calculate what constitutes a day for your report.